# Is it possible to do sequential batch in cassandra.

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra, nosql

Is it possible to do sequential batch in cassandra.
eg:
 insert into table1 and take uuid from this insert operation and pass this to table2 insert statement.
If table 2 insert fails, fail the entire operaion.

If not , whats my best option?

(Its kind of transactional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r best shot is Cassandra Batch statement:
[BATCH - Cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en//cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html)

Combined with "IF EXISTS" constraints (like here: [DELETE - Cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/delete_r.html)) it may be what you need.

However, I don't believe there is a possibility to "insert into table1 and take uuid from this insert operation and pass this to table2 insert statement". You can think of batches in C* as transactions in SQL - it's fully executed or not.

Important things to note:

- batches can span multiple tables in C*
- although batches are atomic, they are not isolated. Some portion of a batch can be executed, in another query you can read those changes, but it may happen they will be revoked because the batch will fail.